# Using game trainers on a laptop without numlock or numpad

Tags: cheats

How can I use pc game trainers on a laptop without numpad and without a `fn` key, because most trainers require you to have numlock keys?

Comment: I asked and answered, but I'm not marking it as **the** accepted answer so more people add to this.

Comment: @TomWijsman I'm talking about `numpad` and not `function` keys.

Comment: What laptop are you talking about then?

Comment: 10,000 views. This question turned out to be a classic question.

Answer (score 10):

Due to the unavailability of **numpad** keys on some laptops, trainers are difficult to use properly, and most people end up using **keyboard re-mappers** which messes up stuff with their registry, and some even recommend plugging in external keyboards.

So I figured this out recently for Windows 7.

Click on your **start menu**, type in **keyboard**.
Click on ***On-Screen Keyboard***, the virtual keyboard now opens.

[image: 1]

Next, click on ***numlock*** which is on the bottom right, then the numlock keys now appear.

[image: 2]

Downside is you have to always minimize the game screen in order to use this.

Hope people find this useful.

Comment: ThanQ Soooooooooo much!!! (^-^)

Comment: I don't get this answer. After you clicked NumLock, how do you use your keyboard to type the 8-directional keys?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest a program such as [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), which allows you to create your own custom keyboard shortcuts, and bind them to any key, key combination, or key sequence.

The benefit of this is that you can enable or disable the shortcuts at will, and you can use the shortcuts even when playing full screen games.

Comment: While autohotkey can work for programs like browser, it doesn't work for some games. They take precedence over autohotkey's mapping.

Answer (score 4):

alexanderpas' suggestion of using autohotkey helped me. I just wanted to add the basic script for mapping 0123456789 to their numpad equivalents.

```
0::Send, {Numpad0}
1::Send, {Numpad1}
2::Send, {Numpad2}
3::Send, {Numpad3}
4::Send, {Numpad4}
5::Send, {Numpad5}
6::Send, {Numpad6}
7::Send, {Numpad7}
8::Send, {Numpad8}
9::Send, {Numpad9}
```

When you first run autohotkey it'll open a default script file, you can just replace its content with the above, save it and and then you're off to the races. Your trainer will now listen to your number keys as if they were on the numpad.

If you're not presented with a default script, you can paste this into a plaintext file ending with .ahk, and load it with autohotkey.

Answer (score 1):

made a script that maps numpad keys to hotkeys
basically:

- Alt+(1,2,3...): for numpad numbers
- Alt+(-,=,.,/): for numpad equivalents
- Ctrl+(8,Enter): for numpad mult and enter

link to file
- http://tinyurl.com/onnavdd